# Date diff between 2 max dates, per day over a given time period

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a sql query to return the difference between a closing time and the final sale of the day for a given location, per day.

The DB schema is something like:

Store_Closing_table(storeCloseTime, storeId)
store_sale_table(saleTime, storeID)

I've written the following(pseudo code):

```
select max(storeCloseTime), 
max(saleTime), datediff(mi, max(saletime), 
max(storeCloseTime)) as timeDifference, storeID 
from store_closing_table a
inner join store_sale_table b
on a.storeid = b.storeid
group by storeid, convert(date, saletime), convert(date, storeCloseTime)
```

Which returns the time difference between the final sale of the day and the store's closing time, but only for the most recent date(i.e the max date).

I'm not sure how to get the max sale date per day and the max store closing time per day(there are situations where the store 'closes' more than once in a day) and then get the datediff between the two.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: I modified the query to include group by clauses, which gets me closer, but I'm getting the difference between each store sale and each store closing time.

I.e. 
store has 3 sales over 3 days. I'm getting close 1 - sale a, close 1 - sale b, close 1 - sale c, close 2 - sale a, close 2 -sale b, close 2 - sale c, close 3 - sale a, close 3 - sale b, close 3 - sale c.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you just need to       "GROUP BY storeID , CAST(saletime as DATE)" at the end

Comment: I would think you'd need the storeID in the Group by as well.

Comment: @WEI_DBA - yes was just adding - and he could put CAST(saletime as DATE) in the select - will it work?

Comment: @AndrewDeighton, I would think so, since that's in the Group By too.

Comment: What are the data types of the storeCloseTime and saleTime?

Comment: They are stored as datetimes.

Comment: Wouldn't  you want to add in the JOIN to make sure the Dates are the same day from both tables?

Comment: The group by almost works, however I'm getting multiple results returned from the query. I.e. if I run this for 2 days, we have 2 daily final sales, and 2 store closing times, I get 4 results, 2 of which date diff the wrong data.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

please try this.

```
WITH cte
AS ( 
       select StoreID,
              CONVERT(DATE, storeCloseTime) AS [Date], 
              max(storeCloseTime) as storeCloseTime,
              max(saleTime) as SaleTime,
         FROM Store_closing_table AS a
         JOIN Store_sale_table AS b ON a.storeid = b.storeid
        GROUP BY StoreID, CONVERT(DATE, storeCloseTime)
    )
       SELECT StoreID, [Date], StoreCloseTime, SaleTime
              datediff(mi, saletime, storeCloseTime) as timeDifference
```